# I want to show Filtered products in Vue Js based upon the selection made by user in 3 diffrent parameters from All products

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

This is step 1 which will appear & user will select one  category from this

```
    <div class="w-100 text-center step-div py-5">

    <h3>step 1 </h3>
    <p class="step-p"> for Men, Women or Unisex</p>

<div class="container">
    <div id="categorytype" class="responsive">

      <div v-for="(type,typeIndex) in types" class="filter-slider-div col-4 p-5" @click= "addfiltertype(typeIndex,type.typeslug)"> 
        <img :src="type.typeImage" class="filter-img mx-auto">
          <p>{{type.typename}}</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Out put will be something like Men,Women,Both,Kids etc  & On click It is saving slug of this type. which I'll share below,

```
    <h3>step 2 </h3>
    <p class="step-p">Select your case size</p>

<div class="container">
    <div id="categorydials" class="responsive">

      <div v-for="(dial,dialIndex) in dials" class="filter-slider-div col-4 p-5" @click= "addfilterdial(dialIndex,dial.dialname)"> 

          <img :src="dial.dialimage" class="filter-img mx-auto">
          <p>{{dial.dialname}}mm</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
```

In step 2 User will select Size it can be anything,

```
    <h3>step 3 </h3>
    <p class="step-p">Select your case colour</p>

<div class="container">
    <div id="categorycolors" class="responsive">

      <div v-for="(color,colorIndex) in colors" class="filter-slider-div p-5" @click= "addfiltercolor(colorIndex,color.colorslug)"> 

          <img :src="color.colorimage" class="filter-img mx-auto">
          <p>{{color.colorname}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

In Step 3 User will select Colour

Now After this   I am updating & saving the slug of these categoies in my js  in method
Here is code how my  Categories are coming from   & saving the category slug in typeslugFilter 
I used alert Js to check if it's working & saving correctly or not & It's Saving the exact slug,

```
var filters = new Vue ({

el: '#categorytype',
data:{
    types: [
        {

            typeId: 1,
            typename: 'Men',
            typeImage: 'assets/images/filter1.png',
            typeslug: 'men',

        },
          {
            typeId: 2,
            typename: 'Women',
            typeImage: 'assets/images/filter2.png',
            typeslug: 'women',
        },
          {

            typeId: 3,
            typename: 'Watches',
            typeImage: 'assets/images/filter3.png',
            typeslug: 'both',
        }


    ] },
    methods: {
    addfiltertype (typeIndex,typeslug) {
        this.typeslugFilter = typeslug;
       // alert(this.typeslugFilter+ '+' + typeslug);
    }
}
});
```

Consider similar code for other two categories with variable dialnameFilter & colorslugFilter,

Now I am trieng to fetch filtered products using below code it's not working for me as of now

I am getting my products from json file & they are working fine I am using typeslug & dialname as category type in single product details & using  productslider as el:   element .

```
<div id="productslider" class="container py-5">
        <p>{{typeslugFilter}}</p>
<div v-for="(variant,variantIndex) in variants" v-if="typeslugFilter === typeslug && dialnameFilter === dialname">
      <div class="watch-slider-div">  
<img :src="variant.variantImage"  class="w-100 py-3">

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Please help me out in this If any tech geek an help will be appreciated

Comment: In your `addfiltertype` method where you mention `this.typeslugFilter = typeslug;`, where is `typeslugFilter` defined? I don't see it in the data object...

Comment: @glitch Can you please help me , I even tried by declaring typeslugFilter as data object  but it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you using `vue-devtools`? If not, please download and use it. More info [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) If yes, do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @glitch I see this error  "typeslugFilter is not defined" & I am unable to tackle this

Comment: That means you need to define `typeslugFilter` in the data object. So within the data object in your Vue instance in `var filters = new Vue()`, add a property called `typeslugFilter`.

Comment: @glitch can you please share your working code as Answer